# Empty partial function in Scala

Tags: scala, partialfunction

It seems to me like the `{ case ... => ... }` syntax for partial functions require at least one `case`:

```
scala> val pf: PartialFunction[String, String] = { case "a" => "b" } 
pf: PartialFunction[String,String] = <function1>

scala> val pf: PartialFunction[String, String] = { }                
<console>:5: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: PartialFunction[String,String]
       val pf: PartialFunction[String, String] = { }
                                                 ^
```

So, what's the best way to define an "empty" partial function? Is there a better way than "manually" overriding `isDefinedAt` and `apply`?

Comment: There's now an empty partial function defined on the `PartialFunction` companion object. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4927

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Map is a PartialFunction so you can do:

```
val undefined: PartialFunction[Any, Nothing] = Map.empty
```

Comment: actually there is also the heavily under-documented `FSM.NullFunction` (which does the same thing). I’m adding docs now.

Comment: Since 2.10 `PartialFunction.empty` is available

Answer (score 51):

Since Scala 2.10 you can use:

```
val emptyPf = PartialFunction.empty[String, String]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
scala> def pfEmpty[A, B] = new PartialFunction[A, B] {
     |   def apply(a: A): B = sys.error("Not supported")
     |   def isDefinedAt(a: A) = false
     | }
pfEmpty: [A, B]=> java.lang.Object with PartialFunction[A,B]

scala> val f = pfEmpty[String, String]
f: java.lang.Object with PartialFunction[String,String] = <function1>

scala> f.lift
res26: (String) => Option[String] = <function1>

scala> res26("Hola")
res27: Option[String] = None
```

As @didierd said in the comments, due to argument variances, a single instance can cover all possible argument types.

```
scala> object Undefined extends PartialFunction[Any, Nothing] {
     |   def isDefinedAt(a: Any) = false
     |   def apply(a: Any): Nothing = sys.error("undefined")
     | }
defined module Undefined

scala> val f: PartialFunction[String, String] = Undefined
f: PartialFunction[String,String] = <function1>

scala> f.lift apply "Hola"
res29: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: He says: a better way than "manually" overriding `isDefinedAt` and `apply` ;)

Comment: @Nicolas: Yes, define a function that does it for you. (`pfEmpty` here) ;)

Comment: @Nicolas: To be honest, I missed that line when I read the question. Thanks for pointing it out! I know my question doesn't satisfy the constraint specified in the question, but anyway I am leaving it here with a hope that it might be useful for someone.

Comment: Given arguments variances, a single instance could do it all: object Undefined[Any, Nothing] {... your impl ...}

Comment: There are two question marks in my post. @missingfaktor gives a great answer to the first one, and implicitly says *"not that I know of"* for the second. :-)  +1!

Comment: Shouldn't apply raise a scala.MatchError exception? That's what applying a PF that's not defined for the input usually does.

Comment: @Hristo: Doesn't matter in this case, I _guess_. (Since `isDefinedAt` is always `false`.)

Comment: Mix of the various solutions: val undefined : PartialFunction[Any, Nothing] = {case _ if false => sys.error("undefined")}

Comment: @didierd: That's good enough to post as a separate answer. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Stealing from everyone, a possible mix of it all :

```
val undefined : PartialFunction[Any, Nothing] = {case _ if false =>
  sys.error("undefined")
}
```

Comment: what good will the `sys.error` do? It will never get executed.

Comment: @aioobe: It has a type `Nothing`.

Comment: A more self-contained expression with type Nothing, which could replace the sys.error call: undefined(undefined).

Answer (score 5):

Shortest one I can think of:

```
{ case _ if false => "" }
```

Comment: Don't you need a `""` after the `=>` for it to be a valid `PartialFunction[String, String]`. If so, it's a bit unfortunate since it's bound to the result type of `""`, no? (Seems like an alternative would be to do `=> throw new RuntimeException()`, but that's perhaps even uglier.) What's your throughts?

Comment: @aioobe You do. I didn't pay attention to the type of the PF.

Comment: Would changing `""` to `null` (or anything else?) make it applicable for all possible partial functions (not just the ones returning `String`)?

Comment: @aioobe No. To make it generally applicable, you have to use `error` or something similar, as they return `Nothing`. `Nothing` is the only subtype of everything.

Answer (score 4):

A solution (which is more a hack) is to ensure that the case is never true: `{ case x if x != x => sys.error("unexpected match") }`

Simple curiosity, why do you need such a function?

Comment: I have an API that accepts a partial function, and I want to provide it with a partial function that's not defined for any argument.

Answer (score 3):

It may be interesting to know that it is planned to add an empty member to the scala library and to see how it is implemented:
https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/6043a4a7ed5de0be2ca48e2e65504f56965259dc

Comment: It's an old question and an old answer. The current implementation can be found there: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/PartialFunction.scala#L246 (l.246-259)